# Mathematica reduces domain when simplifying function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, warning-messages

This question was initially (wrongfully) posted on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668354/mathematica-reduces-domain-when-simplifying-function?noredirect=1#comment7538498_3668354).

I have the following expression:

$$
\sqrt{1 + 10^{\frac{rdb}{10}} + 2^{1 + \frac{rdb}{20}} 5^{\frac{rdb}{20}} \cos(\mathrm{pdiff})}
$$

when applying `FullSimplify` (or `Simplify`) to this function, Mathematica yields
$$
\sqrt{1 + 10^{\frac{rdb}{10}} + 10^{\frac{rdb}{20}} \csc(\mathrm{pdiff}) \sin(\mathrm{pdiff})}
$$

Screenshot from Mathematica:

[image: Screenshot]

This simplification **does** change the domain on which the function is defined, all multiples of $\pi$ are now excluded from the set of allowed values of $\mathrm{pdiff}$.

In my opinion, Mathematica is wrong in that case. Am I right?

Comment: By design those functions produce results that are generically correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = Sqrt[1 + 10^(rdb/10) + 2^(1 + rdb/20) 5^(rdb/20) Cos[pdiff]];

fd = FunctionDomain[expr, {rdb, pdiff}]

(* 10^(rdb/10) + 2^(1 + rdb/20) 5^(rdb/20) Cos[pdiff] >= -1 *)
```

As you stated, `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` change the domain

```
exprs = expr // Simplify

(* Sqrt[1 + 10^(rdb/10) + 10^(rdb/20) Csc[pdiff] Sin[2 pdiff]] *)

FunctionDomain[exprs, {rdb, pdiff}]

(* pdiff/π ∉ Integers && 
 10^(rdb/10) + 10^(rdb/20) Csc[pdiff] Sin[2 pdiff] >= -1 *)
```

This can be avoided by setting the [`Trig`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trig.html) option to `False` in `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`

```
exprs2 = expr // Simplify[#, Trig -> False] &

(* Sqrt[1 + 10^(rdb/10) + 2^(1 + rdb/20) 5^(rdb/20) Cos[pdiff]] *)
```

In this case, no simplification occurs and the domains are identical

```
expr === exprs2 && fd === FunctionDomain[exprs2, {rdb, pdiff}]

(* True *)
```